# How to get client's IP in a java SOAP webservice (JAX-WS)?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I don't know if it's necessary to give more details. The question is as in the title: How to get client's IP in a java SOAP webservice (JAX-WS)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the Source IP of a SOAP requesting client machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647902/how-do-i-get-the-source-ip-of-a-soap-requesting-client-machine)

Comment: use HTTPServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()